# Read entire stdin until EOF in C

Tags: c, hash, stdin

I am writing a program that will generate hashes for files or for a string from stdin. However, fseek and ftell won't work on stdin, so I can't reserve a buffer, rewind stdin to the beginning, and slurp the entire stream. So is there any easy way to do this? Or should I just read n characters each time and send it to the state updating function for each hash?

Comment: "Or should I just read n characters each time and send it to the state updating function for each hash?" - Yes.

Comment: The second option (send n chars at a time, and then final when done) is how I would do it.

Comment: Details might be operating system specific.

Answer (score 2):

If you believe that *stdin* is always textual, you could read entire lines from it using [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html).

If you want to handle arbitrary input (including non-textual *stdin*) you should use [fread(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) in a loop on some rather big block (e.g. 4K or 16K bytes) and take into account partial reads. The block may contain null bytes. You will update the state inside the loop.

You could have partial reads in the middle, e.g. if you are reading from a pipe (with [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) ....) on Linux...